# Как добавить песню в Media Store?

Tags: java, android, id3v2

Я знаю, что с помощью MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI загружать песни с устройства. Но, когда я загружаю песни, то не все грузятся. Встаёт вопрос о том, как пометить песню, или чё-то с ней сделать, чтобы она появлялась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File file = new File(path);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помог

Comment: Рад был помочь)